# Cosmos Db stored procedure appears to return partial aggregates

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I wrote a stored procedure using aggregate functions.

```
SELECT 

MIN(c.Reading) AS MinReading
, MAX(c.Reading) AS MaxReading
, COUNT(1) AS RecordCount

FROM 

Readings c

WHERE 

ReadingId = 1234 
AND ReadingDate >= fromDate
AND ReadingDate <= toDate
```

**Note:** The ReadingId in this example is the partition key.

The same parameter values are returning differenct results. It appears to be returning partial aggregates similar to warnings related to running aggregates in the [web portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query#Aggregates).

Is this a limitation of stored procedures, or is there an option I can set that will prevent partial aggregates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the `queryDocuments` call returns a continuation token, and discard the results if it is not null (or) post-process the min of mins/max of maxes/sum of counts over the partial results to compute the global aggregates.

Cosmos DB always returns partial aggregates for each page of results. The client SDKs internally paginate and compute the complete aggregate over these partial results. Since the query within stored procedures is a low-level API, you may get intermediate partial aggregates. But if you continue to paginate the query results, the final result will be complete/correct.